# Ejecutar función en javascript al cargar página

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas,

Estaba buscando la forma de ejecutar una función en javascript que recibe ciertos parámetros que se obtienen de una consulta a la base de datos, pero no me deja hacer la llamada a la función desde PHP.

Estoy intentando con un simple:

```
<?php 
  info_logros($total_mensajes);
?>
```

Y en JS:

```
$(document).ready(main);

function main(){

    function info_logros(total_mensajes) {
        var mensajes = total_mensajes;

        console.log(mensajes);
    }
};
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Call to undefined function info_logros()

Comment: En vez de $(document).ready(main); debe ser $(document).ready(function () { /* Llamada a función */ }); aunque aún así no veo donde colocas el mensaje generado en el php para mostrarse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje `Call to undefined function info_logros()` lo recibes porque estas llamando desde `PHP` a la función `info_logros` que está definida en `JS`, es decir, no existe en `PHP`.

Así mismo la función `info_logros` esta definida dentro de la función `main`, lo cual la convierte en un *función privada* y por ende inaccesible desde fuera.

Solución:

Dentro del archivo `PHP` crear una función que se ejecutara en el `onload` del documento.

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php
  // Si esta definida la variable
  if (!isset($total_mensajes)) {
?>
<script>
// En el onload
$(function() {
  // Imprimimos el valor de la variable
  var mensajes = <?php echo $total_mensajes; ?>;
  console.log(mensajes);
});
</script>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo he solucionado ya aunque he tenido que desactivar código javascript porque me lo estaba bloqueando por otros errores.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes tu JS dentro de un `index.php` que es donde ejecutas:

```
<?php
  info_logros($total_mensajes);
?>
```

Tendrias que tener entonces algo así en tu Script:

```
$(document).ready(main);

function main(){

  function info_logros() {
    var mensajes = <? echo info_logros($total_mensajes)?>;

    console.log(mensajes);
  }
};
```

Y tendrias que verificar que tu función `PHP` si te devuelva lo que buscas.

**Actualización**

En ese caso lo que se me ocurre es que en un input oculto coloques el resultado de `$total_mensajes` y ya del lado de tu `JS` uses `Jquery` o lo que prefieras para seleccionar el valor de ese input y pasarlo a tu función:

```
function info_logros() {
  var mensajes = $("#input_oculto").val();

  console.log(mensajes);
}
```

Comment: Los datos recibidos con PHP son correctos, es decir `$total_mensajes` es correcto, pero necesito pasar esos valores para modificar algunos estilos con javascript. El JS lo tengo en otro fichero aparte llamado main.js.

Answer (score 0):

Lo importante es tener en cuenta que para `PHP` cualquier elemento `HTML` es tomado como una cadena. Si, una cadena larga pero al fin y al cabo cadena. Así que, realmente no es que `PHP` esté llamando una función de Javascript. Lo que realmente sucede es que `PHP` está imprimiendo una cadena de datos que luego es interpretada por el navegador.

Hay varias maneras.

Una de ellas es dentro de `PHP`. En ese caso:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
 'funcionjs();',
 '</script>';
```

Otra Manera sería escapeando el código Javscript dentro del código `PHP`. Así.

```
<?php
// código php.
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
funcionjs();
</script>
<?php
// código php.
?>
```